# php mvc url manipulation

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, model-view-controller

im trying to build my mvc framework and im encountering some problems regarding url.

i have setup my .htaccess file and i can retrieve the url and explode it to an array.

My problem is when i start clicking links on my page, my framework keeps adding them to the url and i end up with a long url that my framework is unable to use to find the right controller.

EX:

at the root of my site the url is:

localhost/root

when i click a link for the first time, the url change to:

localhost/root/controller/model/params

if i click on another link, my url will be:

localhost/root/controller/model/params/controller/model/params <-- here is where i get the problem because the url is not properly formated for the framework to use it.

I dont know if the problem is in the .htacces or in my framework. What i would like to be able to do is regardless of where i am in my webpage i want the url to be always localhost/root

my .htaccess:

```
Options -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On

Options -Indexes

RewriteBase /root

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

and my main php file is:

```
class main {

    protected $controller ="_default";
    protected $method ="_getDefaultView";
    protected $params;

    public function __construct(){   

        $url = $this->parseUrl();

        if(file_exists('app/controllers/'.$url[0].'.php')){
        $this->controller = $url[0];
        unset($url[0]); 
        }

        require_once('app/controllers/'.$this->controller.'.php');
        $this->controller = new $this->controller;

        if(method_exists($this->controller, $url[1])){
            $this->method = $url[1];
            unset($url[1]); 
        }

        $this->params = $url ? array_values($url) : [];
        call_user_func([$this->controller, $this->method], $this->params);      
    }

    public function parseUrl(){
       if (isset($_GET['url'])){
            return $newUrl = explode('/', filter_var(rtrim ($_GET['url'], '/'), FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
        }
    }
}
```

help is appreciated. :-)

Comment: That is probably because you are constructing your url's like `<a href="controller/model/params">url</a>` when you click on it it becomes `localhost/root/controller/model/params/controller/model/params` try `<a href="/controller/model/params">url</a>`

Comment: if i do that i go to localhost/controller/model/params not to localhost/root/controller/model/params

Comment: @maniteja with your sugestion i got it to work, all i add to do is to construct the links with /root/controller/model/params.  thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

My question was answered by @maniteja where he suggest to contruct the links like this

```
<a href="/controller/model/params">url</a>
```

all i did was to add /root.

credits are yours @maniteja